# eregi > preg_match convert

Tags: php, preg-match, eregi

I need this php code changed to preg_match please

`if(eregi("someurl",$data))`

Answer (score 1):

`if (preg_match('~someurl~i', $data))`. Delimiters can be any single character — I've used `~` instead of `/` used in examples on PHP site, because if you're putting URL in there, you'd have to escape `/`. `i` after the second delimiter is a flag triggering case-insensitivity — PCRE doesn't have separate functions for that.